# HTMLElement.prototype.style undefined on Safari

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

According to MDN, the [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is under `HTMLElement.prototype`.

So when I query it using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, it works well on Chrome and Firefox.

But for some reason on Safari it returns `undefined`, like this:

[image]

I really need to access the style attribute this way (using the prototype) and not sure what the best solution is. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The real answer is probably **no**, you really don't need to access the style property that way? Tell us why you think you need it, and someone most likely has a better alternative.

Comment: Because I'm working on something very low level and I do need to. There are plenty of cases where this sort of convoluted approach is necessary https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor%28HTMLElement.prototype%2C+%22style%22%29%22&type=Code But aside from this, my real question is why this behavior is different on Safari, because this looks like Safari is not following the standard.